# Ratio test for infinite products?

Tags: convergence-divergence, infinite-product

Is the ratio test applicable for testing convergence of infinite products?

In other words, consider the sequence $(a_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ of non-zero real numbers.

Also, consider the product $\displaystyle\mathcal P=\prod_{k=1}^\infty a_k$

Are the following statements true?

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|\lt 1\implies \mathcal P\textrm{ converges}\\ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|\gt 1\implies \mathcal P\textrm{ diverges}$$

Comment: That's not what the ratio test says even for series. In any case, any question about an infinite product of positive reals can be converted into an equivalent question about an infinite series of reals by taking logarithms.

Comment: It is for a number of reasons convenient to say that a product does not converge if the partial products approach $0$. Also, work with the logarithms.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I guess you're referring to the "only if" direction of the first statement?

Comment: I've never understood why anyone would want to say that if the partial products converge to $0$ then the infinite product diverges.

Comment: @zhw, I didn't get what you mean...

Comment: @dat_product: I'm referring to the "only if" direction of both statements.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, Right! My mistake. I figured that out now. Let me edit it to remove the "only if" part. :)

Answer (score 3):

With products, $a_k\to 1$ is the right assumption, otherwise stupid things happen. Just as in series, we usually just assume $a_k \to 0$. So in this context, 
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}}\right| =1
$$
should happen every time.

It's worth noting that 
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$$
converges iff 
$$\sum_{i=1}^k\log(a_k)$$

Think about the exponential function to see why this is. So really, what you want to test is

$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{\log(a_{k+1})}{\log(a_{k})}\right|
$$

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to test if an infinite product converges or diverges is to test the related sum:

$$P=\prod_{k=1}^\infty {(a_k)}$$

can be turned into:

$$\ln{(P)}=S = \sum_{k=1}^\infty {(\ln{a_k})}$$

Now, the product $P$ converges if the sum $S$ converges. If $S$ diverges, then $P$ diverges as well.

You can now use the appropriate test on $S$ (whether it be $n$th term test, ratio test, etc.).

Comment: What if some of the $a_k$'s are negative reals?

Comment: @dat_product: if the sequence $a_k$ is negative infinitely often, then the product diverges (with the convention that approaching $0$ is a form of divergence). If not, you can ignore all of the negative terms.